# Rotate HTML Links and Text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have several links on the same page, and what I want is that every page load, different links and text will appear each time in order.

The code is:

```
<body>
<div id="RotateLink"></div>


<script language="javascript">
var links = new Array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)
document.getElementById("RotateLink").innerHTML = links[randomnumber];
</script>
</body>
```

Here is an image of what i want.

First page load/visitor: http://i.imgur.com/ziZ9JIO.png

Second visitor: http://i.imgur.com/himvsjV.png

And so on.

It will keep rotating in order.

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: What, if anything, does this have to do with PHP? If you're using PHP, rotate the links there, not in the JS. If you're not using PHP, don't tag the question with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost complete. Just add the following shuffle instead of your single random number:

[How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

If you want to keep the order just use

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
   newArray.push(a[(randomNumber + i)%a.length]);
```

Comment: how do I get it to display a link instead of text only? Currently it only displays the text link1, link2, link3, etc.

Comment: Ut oh its one of those neverending question questions.

Comment: '<a href='"+URL+"'>Link</a>

Comment: Thank you Michael. I added the shuffle but it does not seem to work. Where do I put the shuffle?